# What is the meaning of agent in the following context? as I found in Javascript MDN

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, runtime

In Javascript MDN, I read this paragraph but I can't understand what does agent mean?

> To run JavaScript code, the runtime engine maintains a set of **agents** in which to execute JavaScript code. Each **agent** is made up of a set of execution contexts, the execution context stack, a main thread, a set for any additional threads that may be created to handle workers, a task queue, and a microtask queue. Other than the main thread—which some browsers share across multiple **agents**—each component of an **agent** is unique to that **agent**.

please I want a clear explanation.

the link of the page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide/In_depth#run_javascript_run